# Setting up a VLAN isolated from outside

Tags: switch, vlan, hp

I have been tasked with creating a vlan on a HPE 1920 switch that has no access to the outside world but can access all other devices connected to the switch, how do I go about this? I have some limited experience with Cisco routers but none with HPE.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

A VLAN is a Virtual **Local** Area Network, i.e. a layer 2 network.

Hosts within a LAN (being it Virtual or not) need a router to reach other networks (other VLAN or outside world). I.E. a layer 3 network.

So what you need to do is configure access-lists on the router that tells which networks the hosts from this VLAN are allowed to communicate with and forbid all other communication.